# GORM foreign keys without embedded struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

So, using GORM I realize that to use foreign keys, I have to embed the struct in another struct, otherwise gorm won't recognize the relationship like this:

```
type People struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    Card []Card
}

type Card struct {
    ID       int
    Name     string
    PeopleID int
}
```

But, i don't actually want this embeding system. For me, it becomes more troublesome to do sanitization when developing REST apis. So, is there a way to tell GORM about the relationship without actually having to have an embedded struct onto another? Like:

```
type People struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
    //No `Card` object here
}

type Card struct {
    ID       int
    Name     string
    PeopleID int `gorm:"foreignKey:People.ID` //Something like this
}
```

Comment: From your comment about "sanitization when developing REST apis", it sounds like maybe you're unmarshalling untrusted data directly into your GORM structs.  If that's the  case, I'd recommend changing that.  You can decouple by creating corresponding structs for your API calls and copy over the appropriate values one by one.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do when I say "sanitization". My goal was to not have to create a secondary struct just to do this...

Comment: My proposal was made on the reasoning that in exchange for making new code to decouple, you create a more stable and effective security model. Your current approach seems to be eliminate all paths by which malicious data can enter your ORM.  It's analogous to plugging all the leaks, and your current question could be just one leak of many.  Also, it creates a sneaky codependence between your API calls and your ORM definitions, where changes to either can create vulnerabilities in the other.  If you copy a limited set of fields explicitly, both of these problems are mitigated.

Comment: Also I don't mean to be criticising your code too harshly here.  I am just sharing my opinion because I enjoy discussing and hope I may share something you find valuable. If not, that is ok.

Comment: You're kind of misusing the term "embedding", which has significant meaning in Go, especially when you talk about embedding one struct within another.

Comment: Hi @HymnsForDisco, thanks for sharing your approach. What I'm saying is that even creating new structs, I still have to clean incoming data. So, including an array on my model/struct just to state a relational link between tables is not very efficient. My goal is to not load this array at all, always. I understood your solution and it really works well, I was just expecting gorm to have another way of implementing foreign keys, aside from having to have a side-struct typification for the relations... Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @meagar! Yes, i misused the terminology. I actually meant that my struct contains another struct inside, not that is embedded at all. Sorry.